# My image won't show up but the background color shows

Tags: html, css

First while I was styling the css I realized I didn't create a folder for it, so I decided to create a folder for css. Which I named `screen.css` but right after creating the css folder my images stopped showing. I have check the spelling and the tag but nothing seems to help. I did change link tag from `screen.css` to `css/screen.css`

Everything was working fine until I created a folder for the css so I'm guessing the problem might lay there.

An example of the html

```
body
{
    background: url(images/wallpaper.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;
    margin: 0;
    background-color: #e4c17f;
    font-family: 'Nova Square',helvetica, sans-serif;
}

#banner
{
    width: 900px;
    background-color: #a65900;
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 150px;
    background: url(images/banner.jpg);
}

#footer
{
    width: auto;
    background-color: #a65900;
    height: auto;
    background: url(images/name.jpg);
}
```

Comment: is images folder inside the folder you created.. or both folder are on same Level?

Comment: it's not the pic name. As I've said everything was working fine until I created a folder for the css. My code editor gives a preview of the image but now when I roll over the image tag it doesn't give me a preview of the image.

Comment: I've share my answer in comments section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You created the folder CSS therefore probably need to reference the images from your CSS relatively to the images folder...

**A relative path is the path to a  file from the current directory.**

-- images
---- wallpaper.png
-- css
---- screen.css

```
body {   
  background: #e4c17f url(../images/wallpaper.png) repeat-y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this  :**

The Browser will start looking for the image from the folder where you have kept your css

```
background: url(../images/wallpaper.png);
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked! :D

I changed the tag to:

```
background: #e4c17f url(../images/wallpaper.png);
```